# include javax.sound.midi in my android application

Tags: android

facing problem to work with midi file  in android

```
i am unable to find the javax.sound.midi jar file  ..  any where  in google..
from where do i find this jar.

and how do i include this jar

i want the sheet music from  midi files  but  i did'nt get any sample or solution   ..in        android  

plz help me
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html

Comment: sir , that  jmf.jar file does not include javax.sound.midi  ..  sir, from where do i found   the right  jmf.jar

Answer (score 1):

The javax.sound.midi library is not distributed with nor supported on the Android platform. There is, however, a Java implementation of the MIDI file format that can be used with Android projects:

http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Depending on your specific needs it may not be sufficient, but it's certainly a start.